# How to change interval for pyotp.totp module?

Tags: python

```
totp = pyotp.TOTP("base32secret3232")
totp.at(time.time(),60)
print("Current OTP:", totp.now())
otp=totp.now()
text='Your OTP is ' + totp.now()
print totp.verify(otp)
time.sleep(32)
print totp.verify(otp)
```

I want to change interval from default 30 to 60.I should get True output both before and after time.sleep(32) but I'm getting following output.

Answer (score 3):

I think, you want to use;

```
...
print totp.verify(otp, valid_window=1)
time.sleep(32)
print totp.verify(otp, valid_window=1)
...
```

To extend verification interval, to -1, 0, and +1 OTP values, which will return true for 3 intervals.

Documentation is at; https://pyotp.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#pyotp.totp.TOTP.verify

Answer (score 3):

One thing to check is that your verifying totp is set to the same interval as you generator.  This will not work:

```
    secret = pyotp.random_base32()
    totp = pyotp.TOTP(secret, interval=60)
    otp = totp.now()
```

## then later to verify...

```
    totp = pyotp.TOTP(secret)
    totp.verify(otp)
```

## ...will fail..but this will not...

```
    totp = pyotp.TOTP(secret, interval=60)
    totp.verify(otp)
```

Answer (score 2):

Looking at [the source](https://github.com/pyotp/pyotp/blob/5418044c1fdcafe3df05dc1eeea3beb9f166a89b/src/pyotp/totp.py#L20), looks like all you need to do is pass `interval` as a kwarg to the `TOTP` constructor:

```
totp = pyotp.TOTP('secret', interval=60)
# ...
```

Comment: How do you think interval helps?

Comment: OP wanted to change the interval, so uh... this does exactly that.